# Project Euler 8 in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I know my code works to get the correct answer for 4 adjacent integers. But it's not working with 13.

The only thing I can think of is that it can be an issue with an unsigned int, but in Ruby I don't think I'd have that problem because it would change automatically into a Bignum class.

So that means that somewhere in my calculation I am wrong?

Please give me a hint.

```
# Euler 8
# http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=8
# Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number 
# that have the greatest product. 
# What is the value of this product? 


number = []

#split the integer as a string into an array
long_digit = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
            96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
            85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
            12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
            66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
            62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
            30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
            70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
            65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
            52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
            53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
            83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
            82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
            16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
            17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
            24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
            07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
            84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
            05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
            71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"

long_digit.split("").map { |s| number << s.to_i }

#iterate through the array to find the 13 ajacent digits that have the largest product
largest_product = 0
a = 0
#stay within the bounds of the array
while number[a+12]
    current_product = number[a] * number[a+1] * number[a+2] * number[a+3] * number[a+4] * number[a+5] * number[a+6] * number[a+7] * number[a+8] * number[a+9] * number[a+10] * number[a+11] * number[a+12] 
        if current_product > largest_product
            largest_product = current_product
        end 
    a = a + 1
end

puts largest_product
```

Comment: What do you mean by its not working?

Comment: Project Euler says the answer is wrong.
5377010688

Comment: Some readers have not have memorized the Euler Project questions. Don't you think you might open with a reminder of what is being asked by #8?

Comment: @CarySwoveland the instructions are in the comments at the very top of my code.

Comment: Is `'5576689664895'`(yielding the product `23514624000`) the correct answer?

Comment: Yes on `BigNum`. Not having to worry about overflow issues is great, eh? A small thing: the Ruby convention is to indent just two spaces, but that's up to you. Same with naming variables and methods. The convention is to use snake_case (which you've used), but nothing is stopping one to use, say, camelCase. Nearly all experienced Rubiests follow most Ruby conventions. You don't have to, of course, but most of us don't see the point of deviating from it (and, arguably, it makes code easier to read). You might also format your code here so that horizontal scrolling is not required.

Comment: Thanks for the extra advice. It's been so long that I've used Ruby that I forgot the conventions. But really, I really appreciate this extra help.

Answer (score 5):

I think this solution is pretty clean and simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

input = "
73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"
.gsub(/\s+/, '')

puts input.chars
          .map(&:to_i)
          .each_cons(13)
          .map { |seq| seq.reduce(:*) }
          .max
```

`gsub` performs the trimming.

`chars` gets the characters.

`map(&:to_i)` maps all the chars to ints.

`each_cons(13)` gets blocks of consecutive numbers (https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons)

`map { |seq| seq.reduce(:*) }` is going to take each of the consecutive blocks and perform a reduce (multiplying all the numbers of each slice/consecutive block of numbers).

`max` gets the maximum value.

Answer (score 1):

Issue seems to be due to lot of white space chars in the string `long_digit` that are become `0` in the array `number`, thus giving wrong results.

Here is a corrected and simplified version.  After removing newlines and spaces using `gsub`, we now have a 1000 digit number and we get correct answer.

```
number = long_digit.gsub!(/\s/, '').split("").map{ |s| s.to_i }
n = 13
p number.each_cons(n).map{|a| a.reduce {|a, i| a = a * i }}.max
#=> 23514624000
```

Comment: I wanted to make sure I got the answer correct before doing that. I went that route and the answer was wrong...so I made it as simple as possible to let out room for error. I get the same answer as you, but it says that is not the correct answer.

Comment: Okay, I re-read that [link in your code](https://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=8).  It says `Find the thirteen adjacent digits`, so I have updated the answer to also display the 13 digits that provides the highest product.   The answer is 13-digits, not their product

Comment: That solution doesn't work.
It says "What is the value of this product?"
So we both come up with 5377010688, and this answer is not accepted. 
What gives?

Comment: I always thought it was, "...such is the wealth of [tall tales](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tall_tale), greatest of all wealths". (Ref: Wand's profile.)

Answer (score 1):

First, let's fix the string:

```
long_digit.gsub!(/\s|\n/,'')
long_digit.size #=> 1000
```

We can speed this up by eliminating 13-character substrings that contain a zero:

```
shorter_digit_arr = long_digit.split('0').reject { |s| s.size < 13 }
  #=> ["7316717653133",
  #    "6249192251196744265747423553491949349698352",
  #    "6326239578318",
  #    "18694788518438586156",
  #    "7891129494954595",
  #    "17379583319528532",
  #    "698747158523863",
  #    "435576689664895",
  #    "4452445231617318564",
  #    "987111217223831136222989342338",
  #    "81353362766142828",
  #    "64444866452387493",
  #    "1724271218839987979",
  #    "9377665727333",
  #    "594752243525849",
  #    "632441572215539753697817977846174",
  #    "86256932197846862248283972241375657",
  #    "79729686524145351",
  #    "6585412275886668811642717147992444292823",
  #    "863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426",
  #    "96245544436298123",
  #    "9878799272442849",
  #    "979191338754992",
  #    "559357297257163626956188267"]
```

Now, for each element of `shorter_digit_arr`, find the 13-character substring whose product of digits is greatest, then find the largest of those (`shorter_digit_arr.size #=> 24`) products. The main benefit of splitting the string into substrings in this way is that absence of zeroes allows us to perform the product calculations in a more efficient way than simply grinding out 12 multiplications for each substring:

```
res = shorter_digit_arr.map do |s|
      cand = s[0,13].each_char.reduce(1) { |prod,t| prod * t.o_i }
      best = { val: cand, offset: 0 }
      (13...s.size).each do |i|
        cand = cand*(s[i].to_i)/(s[i-13].to_i)
        best = { val: cand, offset: i-12 } if cand > best[:val]
      end
      [best[:val], s[best[:offset],13]]
    end.max_by(&:first)
      #=> [23514624000, "5576689664895"]

puts "max_product: %d for: '%s'" % res
  #=> max_product: 23514624000 for: '5576689664895'
```

The solution is the last 13 characters of:

```
s = shorter_digit_arr[7]
  #=> "435576689664895"
```

The key here is the line:

```
cand = cand*(s[i].to_i)/(s[i-13].to_i)
```

which computes a 13-digit product by multiplying the "previous" 13-digit product by the digit added and dividing it by the digit dropped off.

In finding the maximum product for this element, the calculations are as follows:

```
s = "435576689664895"
cand  = s[0,13].each_char.reduce(1) { |prod,t| prod * t.to_i }
  #=> = "4355766896648".each_char.reduce(1) { |prod,t| prod * t.to_i }
  #   = 6270566400 
best_val = { val: 6270566400, offset: 0 } 

enum = (13...s.size).each
  #=> #<Enumerator: 13...15:each>
```

The elements of this enumerator will be passed to the block by [Enumerator#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-each). We can see what they are by converting `enum` to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [13, 14]
```

We can use [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) to simulate the passing of the elements of `enum` to the block and their assignment to the block variable `i`.

Pass the first element of the enumerator (`13`) to the block:

```
i = enum.next
  #=> 13 
cand = cand*(s[i].to_i)/(s[i-13].to_i)
  #  = 6270566400*(s[13].to_i)/(s[0].to_i)
  #  = 6270566400*(9)/(4)
  #  = 14108774400 
cand > best[:val]
  #=> 14108774400 > 6270566400 => true
best = { val: cand, offset: i-12 }
  #=> { val: 14108774400, offset: 1 }
```

Pass the second element (`14`) to the block:

```
i = enum.next
  #=> 14 
cand  = cand*(s[i].to_i)/(s[i-13].to_i)
  #=> = 14108774400*(s[14].to_i)/(s[1].to_i)
  #   = 14108774400*(5)/(3)   
  #   = 23514624000 
cand > best[:val]
  #=> 23514624000 > 14108774400 => true
best = { val: 23514624000, offset: 2 }
```

All elements of the enumerator have now been passed to the block. We can confirm that:

```
i = enum.next
  #=> StopIteration: iteration reached an end
```

The result (for `shorter_digit_arr[7]`) is:

```
[best[:val], s[best[:offset],13]]
  #=> [23514624000, "435576689664895"[2,13]]
  #   [23514624000, "5576689664895"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation. How does your solution differ in performance compared to wand's code below?

Comment: I expect this would be quite a bit faster, since I compute the products of the digits for most of the 13-character strings by performing one multiplication and one division on the product just computed for the "previous" 13-character string, rather than doing 12 independent multiplications for each 13-character string.

Comment: What is the `&` in this line:
`end.max_by(&:first)`

Comment: Michael, as you know, `:first` is a symbol that represents a method. `&` is an operator that acts on that symbol. It does two things: it converts the associated method to an instance of `Proc` and then calls the proc.  The result is the same as `end.max_by { |e| e.first }`. More generally, you will generally see `receiver.my_method1 { |e| e.my_method2}` written `receiver.my_method1(&:my_method2)`. I've left out some details, such as when the argument is already a proc. [Here's a fuller explanation](http://www.skorks.com/2013/04/ruby-ampersand-parameter-demystified/).